# When creating global kernel variables where do I actually declare the variable to be used?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, global-variables, system-calls

So I'm doing a homework assignment for an OS class and in it we're required to create kernel variables to be used in system calls.  I understand that in order to do this, you have to use code similar to:

`int global_var; 
EXPORT_SYMBOL(global_var)`

My question is - where do I put this code? I've written a file with system calls within it, but I don't know where to actually put the aforementioned two lines, looking online has made me more confused than anything, so any help would be appreciated.

(As an example, I've included some code using the global variable above)

```
    extern int global_var = 0;
    asmlinkage long sys_hello(void) {

     printk(kern_info "hello earth %i\n", global_variable);

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: `My question is - where do I put this code?` - Put the code into any existed `.c` file which is compiled for kernel. Or create a new source file and modify corresponded Makefile, so the source file will be compiled into kernel. See [Documentation/kbuild/makefile.txt](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt) for more details. As you don't create a kernel module, construction `EXPORT_SYMBOL` is unnecessary.

Comment: EXPORT_SYMBOL tells kernel that variable is global and it can be used from other kernel parts or modules. If you don't export symbol, you won't be able lo resolve var's address by it's name from other module or kernel part. EXPORT_SYMBOL is a part of post compile linkage.